# "The token is invalid" when trying to setup Paypal recurring payments with ActiveMerchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I feel like a lot of the documentation on this is outdated, but this is what I have been trying so far:

I am using the `ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway` gateway.

First I setup the purchase and redirect the user to Paypal:

```
response = gateway.setup_purchase price,
  return_url: <confirm url>,
  cancel_return_url: <cancel url>,
  items: [
    {
      name: 'My Item',
      quantity: 1,
      description: "My Item Description",
      amount: price
    }
  ]
redirect_to gateway.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

This works, I can sign in as a sandboxed buyer and confirm the payment, which brings me back to `<confirm url>` from above. In the confirmation, I do:

```
response = gateway.recurring price, nil,
  token: params[:token],
  period: 'Year',
  frequency: 1,
  start_date: Time.now,
  description: 'My Item Subscription'
```

When I do this, I receive an invalid token error from Paypal in the `response` variable. The token seems to be fine, it is present in the URL when I am brought back to the confirmation URL. I'm then taking it directly (`params[:token]`) and sending it back to Paypal.

Am I doing something completely wrong? Like I said, it seems like a lot of the documentation for this type of process is outdated (or maybe what I am trying is the stuff that is outdated...)

Comment: We don't have recurring payments set up, but we've got Paypal express gateway working for ActiveMerchant working at http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk (dev app) -> would you like me to paste code?

Comment: @RichPeck : I am trying the express checkout, but I'm facing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809440/test-paypal-express-gateway-redirecting-to-live-and-not-sandbox) problem. Could you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the source code for ActiveMerchant's Paypal express checkout gateway, I came to the conclusion that it's simply outdated when dealing with recurring payments. I switched to the [paypal-recurring](https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring) gem instead and everything worked fine.